# Machine Learning Classification of Changes in a Time Series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, train

I would like to classify the **changes** in the time series depicted in the figure below—representing an angular position history of a robot about the vertical axis—into increment/decrement of roughly (not necessarily exactly) ±90°/±180° (i.e., four classes; which could also be symbolic). In other words, I aim to detect any change in the angle history, and classify it over time within one of the four numeric categories {-90, +90, -180, +180} (or symbolic categories {up90, down90, up180, down180}).

[image]

Please note again that I am specifically dealing with classifying the changes in the time series, rather than classifying the entire time series at once. I attempted to use the angle rate-of-change (i.e., angular velocity; figure below: the blue curve is raw and the orange curve is smoothed) to detect any change in the time series, but was not 100 % successful to discriminate between a "+90°" and a "+180°" angle jump for example. Besides, I think I need to use a “sliding window” technique in solving this problem, but don't know how to implement it.

[image]

Therefore, (1) I was wondering if there is any idea on how to reliably **train** an ML classification algorithm given this type of data to achieve the stated objective? (2) What should be the input data (features), and (3) how to represent the output data (labels)? A test data is represented by the figure below.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Does the entire time series belong to a class or do you classify each time instant?

Comment: I aim to classify each time instant.

Comment: @AEW Based on what criteria? Do you include history or just the data from that one instant?

Comment: I believe the ML algorithm should learn from the entire data history.

Comment: So it's allowed to look at both the future and the past of the curve to help decide? (This is called __smoothing__.)

Comment: Yes, the whole time series will be provided at once.

Comment: That sounds a lot like using the future to predict the present. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Actually using the past to predict the future.